# Load Offline content in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am caching HTML contents of UIWebView in a string and trying it to load back when application is offline

```
 if ([hostReach hostConnectionStatus] == NotReachable) {
        NSString *cachedResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self responseHTMLData] encoding:NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding];
        [webView loadHTMLString:cachedResponse baseURL:final_url];

    }
```

cachedResponse is an HTML data in it but the problem is UIWebView  fails to load this data

```
// WebView Delegate
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   return YES;
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
   // error description "connection is offline"
}
```

How to I load HTML contents in UIWebVIew when its offline

Comment: What is the value of `final_url`. All resources referenced in the HTML file must be cached as well, and `final_url` needs to be a path to those cached resources.

Comment: @user3386109 that did worked. thanks .you add that as an ans and I can accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All resources referenced in the HTML file must be cached as well, and the `baseURL` needs to be a path to those cached resources.

Comment: Is internet connection required to load again same HTML content ?

Comment: @iThink if you have all the resource needed by HTML file, you don't need internet connection to load the HTML file.

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSString *pathLogo = @"Your Directory Path";
NSURL *baseURL_Logo = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathDir];
NSMutableString *contentHTML = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[contentHTML appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@Image.png\"/>\n",baseURL_Logo];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.